# Inconsistent size pdf device

Tags: r, pdf, r-grid

The pdf device in R seems to have an inconsistent output size.
For example:

```
library(grid)
pdf("myplot1.pdf", width=.51, height=.255) 
grid.rect(width = 1, height=1, gp=gpar(col="red"))
dev.off()
```

results in an incomplete rectangle:

[image]

When the width and height are pretty rounded,

```
pdf("myplot2.pdf", width=.5, height=.25) 
grid.rect(width = 1, height=1, gp=gpar(col="red"))
dev.off()
```

the rectangle is depicted well:

[image]

This problem does not occur with other devices such as `png`. It seems like the size of the pdf file is rounded down, while R still uses the original size to plot.

Comment: Did you have a question?  Are you asking how to output a border even with an irregular size or are you asking why it does that?

Comment: Yes, both are of interest, but especially the first one: how to output the border irrespective of the pdf size.

Answer (score 2):

I've found got the solution.
Apparently, the pdf document is rounded down to the nearest 1/72 of an inch. Still don't know why.

Anyway, this wrapper will do the trick:

```
pdf2 <- function(file, width, height, ...) {
    rnd <- function(x) x %/% (1/72) / 72
    do.call("pdf", c(list(file=file, width=rnd(width), height=rnd(height)), list(...))) 
}
```

Comment: Most likely related: the unit 1/72th of an inch, a.k.a. the *typographic point*, is the internal unit of measurement of PDFs. I'd have to consult the specifications whether or not a floating point value for document size is allowed. It may just be a limitation of R's PDF engine.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application, you can shorten the dimensions of the box:

```
pdf("myplot3.pdf", width=.51, height=.255) 
grid.rect(height=0.95,width=0.95, gp=gpar(col="red"))
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
pdf("myplot4.pdf", width=.5, height=.25) 
grid.rect(height=0.95,width=0.95, gp=gpar(col="red"))
dev.off()
```

[image]

It's an imperfect solution but may be functional.

Comment: That would be my fallback solution. Not ideal at all, since in some cases there is space left between the border and the boundaries of the image. I tried to calculate how much the box should be shrunk, but didn't know how to do this, since I don't know why and when it behaves like that.

Comment: Agreed.  I had this problem when creating PDF output in a latex document, and this is the solution that I had to resort to.